# Correct way to alter markup as html within theme_preprocess_container?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

On my node edit form I've got a field widget that needs some information added to it. Before my alterations, the kint dump of `$variables['children']` looks like:

[image]

However, after manually setting `$variables['children']`, the dump looks like:

[image]

Before alteration, html renders correctly. However, afterward it is all just rendered as a string with the HTML displaying on the page.

[image]

I've tried using the `create()` method instead that's shown as available under:

[image]

...but it doesn't do anything at all.

I've also instead tried changing `$variables['element']['display']['#markup']`, but that doesn't have any visible effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a markup object, but you can use the `create()` method on a new markup object to replace the old one.

```
$variables['children'] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create('<div>Manually set</div>');
```

By the way, you are modifying a twig debug message which won't be there in a production environment.

Comment: Ah, \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create() is what I was looking for. And thanks for the heads up on the debug element -- ended up finding the proper one in the end.